# componentWillUpdate read the old state

Tags: reactjs

I thought that when `componentWillUpdate` was called, I could read the latest state i.e. states from `this.state`. However, I realized I was wrong after I checked the document more closely. The fact is that even if `componentWillUpdate` is invoked after `this.state`, it still reads the 'Old' state. What is the point of this design? How is `componentWillUpdate` useful?

Comment: @user120242 ,What surprise me is that `componentWillUpdate` read the old state while `render` read the latest state .It seem `componentWillUpdate` do not expect you touch the state

Comment: will update is exactly what it sounds like... it will update in a second. so the current state on it at that moment is whatever it is previously (because it hasn't actually updated yet). you can accept the next state that its transitioning to as a parameter in the function so that you can see what it will be transitioning to. in the render it has updated and the render is triggered to show the new data that it got.

Answer (score 5):

`componentWillUpdate` is a React Lifecycle method (see here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods) that is invoked immediately before rendering, which is what a call to `this.setState` will do. That's why the old state is still available to you, and how it could be useful to you is beyond the scope of this site imho (could be used to make an api call logging an action has occurred noting the previous state or all kinds of things).

Note that `componentWillUpdate` does in fact receive the nextState as an object passed to it so you could access them there if you do want them as well.

If you're looking to get the state after it has rendered, you should look into `componentDidUpdate`, which will then have the old state.

Comment: What surprise me is that componentWillUpdate read the old state while render read the latest state .It seem componentWillUpdate do not expect user touch the state. If so,I do not know how this lifecycle method useful (I fail to understand your example )

Comment: Thanks ! `nextProps` and `nextState` are actually available in `componentWillUpdate`

Comment: ComponentWillUpdate is called before the new state has been set, that's it's purpose. I'm confused what you mean by "componentWillUpdate do not expect user touch the state", it'll only ever be called if the state/props have changed. It's just called before the render is all.

Comment: Ah ok yes they are :)

Comment: @BenHare he's correct in that respect; componentWillUpdate is designed not to modify state, just react to it changing

Comment: Yeh,if `nextProps` and `nextState` are not available, this method is quite useless. I just learn it we can got those two params.